# What curses leave marks or scars?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape, unforgivable-curse

We all know Harry got his lightning-shaped scar from the Killing Curse. However he was the first one to survive, thus the first one to obtain a scar from it. But Hagrid tells Harry that being touched by dark magic can leave scars.

> Never wondered how you got that mark on yer forehead? That was no
>   ordinary cut. That's what yeh get when a Powerful, evil curse touches
>   yeh -- took care of yer mum an' dad an' yer house, even -- but it didn't
>   work on you, an' that's why yer famous, Harry. No one ever lived after
>   he decided ter kill 'em, no one except you, an' he'd killed some o' the
>   best witches an' wizards of the age.

H.P.S.S Chapter 4, The Keeper of the Keys

So does that mean there are other dark curses that leave scars? We know that the Imperius Curse, the Killing Curse and the Cruciatus Curse do not normally leave any marks. Sectumsempra leaves a scar sometimes, if the person doesn't end up dying, like George and Malfoy for example.

> When Snape had performed his counter-curse for the third time, he half lifted Malfoy into a standing position. 'You need the hospital wing. There may be a certain amount of scarring, but if you take dittany immediately we might avoid even that … come …'

H.P.H.B.P Chapter 24, Sectumsempra

But what other curses leave marks? Does anybody know what Hagrid was referring to? Surely no one else got a scar from the Killing Curse..

Comment: I know that there is a question similar to this. But they are not the same. The other question asks who are the other people with scars similar to Harry's. And I'm asking about the curses themselves that give people scars not names of people who have gotten marks or scars from curses. There is a subtle difference that does not the same question.

Comment: Expelliarmus. Lockhart and Snape learnt it the hard way :p

Comment: There was the unnamed curse which gave Dumbledore a scar the shape of the London Underground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dark magic can leave marks, but it’s never specified which spells.

When George’s ear is cursed off, the reason it can’t be grown back is because it was a result of Dark magic.

> “Mrs Weasley had staunched his bleeding now, and by the lamplight Harry saw a clean, gaping hole where George’s ear had been.
>
> ‘How is he?’
>
> Mrs Weasley looked round and said, ‘I can’t make it grow back, not when it’s been removed by Dark Magic. But it could have been so much worse … he’s alive.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 5 (Fallen Warrior)*</sup></sub>

The spell that caused this particular injury was Sectumsempra, which was also the one that nearly caused Draco to have scarring. No other Dark magic spells are mentioned that could also cause scarring.

## Hagrid might have just been referring to Harry’s specific case.

Hagrid might not have been referring to any other particular Dark magic that causes scars. No one else survived the Killing Curse, so he probably meant that Harry’s scar specifically was a result of powerful Dark magic and that it makes sense for Harry to have had a bit of damage from it, rather than any other cases.

## The spell creating the Dark Mark leaves a permanent mark.

While this might not be *quite* what was pictured in the question, the Dark Mark that’s on the Death Eaters’ forearms cannot be removed, even by magic.